# Climate in an Alderson Disk

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, climate, atmosphere, megastructures

First, i want to accept that alderson disks are basically imposible to create, due to a variety of reasons.

With that out of the way, i want to ask what would be the hypothetical climate of an Alderson Disk assuming it has an earth-like atmosphere, taking into account one of it's extremes would be extremely hot and the other extremely cold. How would temperatures, winds, and all that fun stuff be in troughout the disk?

I understand this may be very difficult (or straight up impossible) to answer, due to the pseudo-scientific nature of the Alderson disk. So if you think i should delete the questio, let me know.

Once again, thanks for your time!

Comment: What is an Alderson disk?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alderson_disk

Comment: Does the sun Bob up and down?

Comment: Lots of twilight. "High noon" would still have the sun right on the horizon, possibly not even showing its full face.

Comment: I would like the sun to bop as high as possible, as long as it isn't too disruptive.

Answer (score 1):

A defining feature of Alderson Disks is the oscillation or 'bobbing' sun in the central gap. As on Earth or any typical planet, climate will depend largely on two factors derived from this sun:

**1. Angle of incidence**

[Solar intensity varies proportionate to the angle above the horizon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_of_Sun_angle_on_climate). The lower the angle the larger the area covered, the more the energy is dissipated and the cooler the climate. On Earth this angle ranges from 90° (overhead) to 0° (below the horizon). The nature of an Alderson Disk means the sun never reaches that 90° mark, actually falling far short of it. Without the overhead light you won't have climates defined by hot and year-round growing seasons: no tropical rainforests or tropical savannahs.

[image: An Alderson Disk, framed to show the range of climates]

**2. Distance from sun**

Related to the above, the distance from the sun will also play a role, as this will determine the angle of incidence. The nearer to the middle, the higher the angle and vice versa. The outer expanses of the Disk will be arctic-like, receiving the least amount of solar energy and having the lowest angle. The inner edge will be the inverse, but likely won't get more light/energy than the temperate zones on Earth.

Here you can cheat the system in your favour by using a hotter star, but this will not change the angle of incidence, just widen the habitable zone.

Otherwise your Disk's climates will be influenced by oceanic and atmospheric currents and precipitation. If the Disk spins at all there will be a Coriolis Effect at play as on Earth.

Comment: How do you think the currents would behave in an alderson disk? Is it even possible to calculate, seeing how different it is from a spherical planet? +1, btw

Comment: Currents will be influenced by the Coriolis effect as mentioned, but I can't be more specific than that without seeing ocean/land placement. I expect there would be a single atmospheric cell.

Answer (score -1):

### It depends on how you design the disc

Building Alderson disc's requires a tech level that is so high that climate is a minor engeneering concern. You need advanced active support, magnetic monopoles and/or metric spacetime engeneering to build such a structure. Probably all three of these technologies and then some.

Strictly speaking you would have a disc that is very hot near the sun and cold far from it. How much energy a given point on the disc receives depends on the inverse square of its distance from the star (star beeing defined as whatever they are using as an engery source, it could be a penrose sphere covered in radiators as well or a matter energy converter).

Thus would result in an ever dimming twighlight zone, not unlike the conditions one would find around the terminator of a tidally locked world. However, there are options to improve this design.

For once one could shadow out the sun totally with a huge, artificial mountain rage near the inner edge. This would create an icy expanse, perfect for large scale computation. Most of the discs mass would in any case be hydrogen, so it could be used as a heatsink  and fuel reserve.

If you wa t to make the disk more habitable for biological entities, you would have to illuminate it better. The inner mountains are still an option if you dislike the idea of twighlight. For illumination there are two basic options. Either you use mirrors, which levitate over the central energy sources poles or high towers with lightsources on top.

The mirror idea could use either atlas towers or solar statites. If the mirrors rotate, their structures can create a day-night cycle. The illumination towers (also atlas towers) are pretty selfexplainetory.

TLDR: The climate will be what ever you want it to be.